# Jquery Ajax, "SyntaxError: invalid object initializer" with dataTable & "posting" data

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

This I think is simple but a little confused on the error because I of the way dataTables requests to use the Ajax function.  Jquery, Tabledata with Ajax POST function.

Works:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "DataTables-1.9.2/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
    "sAjaxSource": "rquery_v1.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        $.ajax( {
            "dataType": 'json', 
            "type": "POST", 
            "url": sSource, 
            "data": aoData,
            "success": fnCallback
        } );
    }
} );
```

when I attempt to pass an additional field "qid" it fails

Fails:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "DataTables-1.9.2/extras/TableTools/media/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
        },
    "sAjaxSource": "rquery_v1.php",
    "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
        $.ajax( {
            "dataType": 'json', 
            "type": "POST", 
            "url": sSource, 
            "data": { aoData, qid: 1 },
            "success": fnCallback
        } );
    }
} );
```

It is/was requested to have the quotes around "data" so that is a bit confusing on why. but it fails with "SyntaxError: invalid object initializer"

Thanks sure it is a simple issue as it is Syntax.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Shouldn't `aoData` have a value in the example that fails? There should be key, value pairs in `"data": { aoData, qid: 1 }`

Comment: Sorry that was a copy paste issue, that was closing the form Ready function.  Thanks

Comment: what is `aoData` and what is `qid`? I think you're missing the key for aoData and need to wrap qid in quotes

Comment: aoData is an array, I think that may be what is tripping me up. trying to pass an array (that is part of the datatable add-on) and my data pair.

Comment: What I mean is that you should have a key for `aoDada`. `"data": { keyName: aoData, qid: 1 }`

Comment: Same error with --> "data": { aoData, "qid": 1 }, <---   QID is going to be one of the few variables will be passing in in the POST function.

Comment: aoData is an array. From what I am seeing..  So I don't think it requires a Key next to it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a key for your `aoData` parameter, e.g.

```
'data':{myCoolArray:aoData, qid:1}
```

...which gives your aoData array a name `myCoolArray` by which you can access it on the server.

Cheers

Comment: Good enough..  "aoData" I think was an array from DataTables add-in that was being populated if you are doing server-side handling of the data, but I am not so it was empty when doing some additional testing.  So dropping it all together is AOK.  Your solution passes correctly unsure if it works with "aoData" being an array but don't really care as the array of info in "aoData" is not being used server side..  That was "the issue" Thanks